# How to avoid SMR HDDs

Tags: hard-disk

I recently bought a batch of 6 "WD elements" external HDDs and quickly found out that - for three of them - the write performance was precipitously degradating. Circumstantial evidence points to shingled (SMR) technology: format followed by trim restores acceptable writing speed, again degrading when used space goes above 50%.

These disks (used for backup) need replacing, and I am of course going to avoid SMR like the plague, but how? Transparency in labeling does not appear to be WD's forte, and I am wondering how to tell SMRs apart from non-SMR, i.e. brands and telltale labels I should look for.

Ideas? TIA

Comment: Send an e-mail as high up in WD as you can find, telling them why you won't be buying any more of their drives until they stop doing this!

Comment: The ultimate answer is to buy ALL SSD either SATA or NVME then you won't get any SMR drives as SSD don't use that technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't guarantee 100% reliability but you could use https://nascompares.com/answer/list-of-wd-cmr-and-smr-hard-drives-hdd/. I've looked up my drives and they're all correctly reported as CMR.

A while back, when customers had bad experience with server drives that were SMR in disguise, WD ended up issuing a semi apology with an explanation of their Red drive strategy: https://blog.westerndigital.com/wd-red-nas-drives/

For the past 5 years, I've been buying dozens of drives ranging from 8 to 20TB, all from their Elements brand (most of the time, it's a WD Purple inside the case) and so far, so good. When I found their blog post in 2020, I took it as a good rule of thumb that 8TB and above == CMR, no matter the "color". I've applied this logic since then and so far, not one SMR drive in the bunch. Quite a few Helium filled drives though.

But if you're less confident with this logic, it doesn't hurt to double check with the first link.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of Googling found [How-To-Geek - So Is SMR Bad? Which Drive Type Should I Choose?](https://www.howtogeek.com/803276/cmr-vs.-smr-hard-drives-whats-the-difference/) which seems to also agree with [Wikipedia - Shingled magnetic recording](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingled_magnetic_recording) (though that article has lots of 'low data' markers) in that only Seagate are at present clearly stating which drives contain which technology.

[Seagate - Which Drive Has What?](https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/products/cmr-smr-list/)

At least it looks like if you switch allegiance, you have *one* reliable source.

In any decision regarding HD purchase, I would always take a look at the Backblaze stats - pretty much the only unbiased research out there & a valuable *free* resource to the community at large.
[Backblaze Drive Stats for 2022](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/backblaze-drive-stats-for-2022/)
The only downside of their research is just how much data there is to wade through even after they've boiled it down into almost manageable chunks.